Passing The ODCIVARCHAR2LIST from java to Oracle database 19c
I have Producer that get Serial of my data and update status, get data from view and update data in database, by java I pass the Serial array that I want update but in my case I got Error : : 17023 ->Unsupported feature: createArrayOf
Here My JAVA code :
    public int acceptsGoodsInDepots(String userId, String[] ids) throws SQLException {
        int insertedCount = 0;
        try (Connection connection = JDBCPoolConnectionAPI.getPoolConnection().getConnection();
             CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call change_trace_goods_for_aceepts(?, ?, ?)}")) {
            callableStatement.setString(1, userId);
            Array serialArray = connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", ids);
            callableStatement.setArray(2, serialArray);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
            callableStatement.execute();
            insertedCount = callableStatement.getInt(3);

        }
        return insertedCount;
    }


And Here My Producer :
create or replace PROCEDURE         change_trace_goods_for_aceepts ( 
    p_receiver IN VARCHAR2,
    p_good_serials IN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST,
    p_inserted_count OUT NUMBER
) AS
    v_insert_count NUMBER := 0; -- Initialize insert count
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..p_good_serials.COUNT LOOP
        DECLARE
            v_trace_status NUMBER;
            v_city  VARCHAR2(32) ; v_province  VARCHAR2(32) ; v_sender  VARCHAR2(32) ; v_rec VARCHAR2(32);
        BEGIN
            -- Get the goods status
            SELECT TRACE_STATUS , CITY , PROVINCE , SENDER_ID , RECEIVER_ID INTO v_trace_status , v_city , v_province , v_sender , v_rec
            FROM VIEW_DEPOTS_GOODS
            WHERE GOODS_SERIAL = p_good_serials(i);

            -- Check if goods status is 4
            IF v_trace_status = 1 or  v_trace_status = 3 or v_trace_status is null THEN
                -- Insert into TABLE_TRACE_GOODS
                INSERT INTO TABLE_TRACE_GOODS (GOOD_SERIAL, SENDER, RECEIVER, PROVINCE, CITY, STATUS)
                VALUES (p_good_serials(i), v_sender, v_rec, v_province, v_city, 4);
                v_insert_count := v_insert_count + 1; -- Increment insert count
            END IF;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                -- Handle if goods serial not found
                NULL;
        END;
    END LOOP;
    
    -- Set the OUT parameter to the insert count
    p_inserted_count := v_insert_count;
END;

I need pass String array from java into oracle sql producer.
what is my mistake? what can I do for resolve it? in some way the said create database object or type but its common way and I think we have some answer without change oracle database type or create new one.

From the documentation: Oracle JDBC does not support the JDBC 4.0 method createArrayOf ... Use the Oracle specific method oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.createARRAY instead.

See my answer here for an example using createARRAY.

@MT0 the answer create new Table for doing such common things.

@S.kh That answer provides a [MRE] for that particular question and the table and types are relveant for that question  - you need to adapt it for your question which means modifying your code to stop use createArrayOf and to use createARRAY instead but you should not need to create any new types or tables (just use the built-in ones).

Also, connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", ids); is wrong as you do not want to create an array of VARCHAR (since VARCHAR is a single string and is not an array) you want to create an array of the collection data-type which would be SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST.

You want something like (untested as I do not have your database tables):
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;

callableStatement.setString(1, userId);
ARRAY a = ((OracleConnection) con).createARRAY("SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST", ids);
((OraclePreparedStatement) callableStatement).setARRAY(2, a);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
callableStatement.execute();

Depending on how your connections are managed, you may need to unwrap the connection to get to the underlying OracleConnection object rather than casting.

Thanks, use this before and didn't work but by your changes it work.
